# MPMoviePlayerController stop button not working

Tags: uibutton, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I'm trying to use the same button to play and stop my radio stream, my button plays fine, then when i press for it to stop, it only stops for a few seconds then starts playing again.

here is the code im using.

```
- (IBAction)playStream:(id)sender {
self.buttonPressed.selected = !self.buttonPressed.selected;

NSString *urlAddress = @"http://67.159.28.74:8730";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];


player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;



player.view.hidden = YES;

self.myPlayer = player;

[self.view addSubview:self.myPlayer.view];



if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped){
    [self.myPlayer play];}
else if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying){
   [self.myPlayer stop];}
```

}

Comment: anyone any feed back would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Every time you press the button, a new instance of the movie player is created. Thus the check `if (player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped)` will always return YES, and thus start the movie.